# Json remote validation function from MVC View

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to remotely check controller if a member is blocked from view.  The form  which triggers this check is not strongly bound to a model.  The controller method is triggerted but the MemberID gets to the controller as null

```
function BlockedMember() {
    var isExist = false;
    var m_userid = {
        act: 'isBlocked',
        MemberID: $('#txtMemberID').val()
     };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/member-blocked', 
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
       data: { 'act': 'isBlocked', 'MemberID': $('#txtMemberID').val() },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            if (result == 0) {
                isExist = false;
                //return true;
            }
            else if (result == 1) {
                //alert("Invalid");
                isExist = true;
                //return false;
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            $('#modalMessage').modal('show');
            $('#modalMessage').find('#modalBody').html(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
    return isExist;
}
```

Below is the controller action

```
[Route("member-blocked/{act?}/{MemberID?}/", Name = "getmemberstatus")]
    public ActionResult GetBlockedMember(string act, int? MemberID)
    {
        string mid="";
        mid = Request["act"];
        var isBlocked = db.Members.Where(a => a.Mcode == MemberID && a.MemberOk == false)
       .Select(c => new { c.MemberId, c.FullName });
        return Json(isBlocked, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I need help

Comment: Your `BlockedMember()` function will always return `false` because ajax is async and the line `return isExist;` will execute before your ajax `success` callback. And you query will never return `"0"` or `"1"` so its unclear what you think this code will do. Note also MVC comes with a `[Remote]` attribute which does this all out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stephen Muecke mentioned in the comment, your function is returning a boolean value even before you get your response from ajax. Remember ajax is asynchronous.

Also, Looks like your action method is a GET action method and from your javascript code, you are trying to make a POST call with some data in the request body. You don't need to do that. You can simply do a get request using $.get.

```
function CheckBlockedMember() {

    var url = "/member-blocked/isBlocked/"+$('#txtMemberID').val();

    $.get(url, function (result) {
       // We got some response from the server action method now.

        console.log(result);
        // show some message to user based on the result
        // Read further down to see the response data type

        if (result) {

            alert("User is blocked");
            //Or hide or show some message to user
           // Ex :$("#SomeMsgDiv").html("User is blocked")

        } else {

            alert("User is not blocked");
            //Hide or show some message to user
           // Ex :$("#SomeMsgDiv").html("User is not blocked")

        }
    });

}
```

Now you can call this `CheckBlockedMember` method from somewhere else in your code. foe example

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on("change","$txtMemberID",function(e){
     CheckBlockedMember();
  });
});
```

Another thing to note is, in your action method the data you are returning from the action method is an array like this. (Since you are simply calling `select` on the results returned by your where clause).

```
[{
    "MemberId": 123,
    "FullName": "Scott"
}]
```

If your where clause returns more than one record, the result will have more than one item in the array. Since you just want to know whether the user is blocked or not, you may simple return a boolean value as the response.

```
public ActionResult GetBlockedMember(string act, int? MemberID)
{
   //isBlocked will have true of false based on the where clause execution
    bool isBlocked = db.Members
           .Any(a => a.Mcode == MemberID && a.MemberOk == false);

    return Json(isBlocked, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: thanks  @Shyju very much for this.  How do i make the ActionResult for GetBlockedMember  retur false if the  MemberID does not exist?

Comment: The `Any` method will return true or false based on the condition you passed it it. So if It gets at least one record which matches the condition, It will return true. Else false.

Comment: I want only members who are registered and have memberOk as true to be able to  proceed with the form. but when I try  with any arbitrary Id it passes as not blocked.

Comment: Since i do not know what your db schema and business requirement, it is hard for me to tell it. I answered your original question. I guess, if you fix your linq query you will get what you want.